# Existe una manera de escribir una condición en sql y cuando esa condición no se cumpla me pinte la solicitud en un reporte?

Tags: sql-server, report, ssrs

Buenas tardes a Todos.

Me encuentro realizando un reporte de incumplimiento de tareas, el mismo lo estoy trabajando con SQL Server y con Reporting Services.

Tengo un campo el cual de se llama `diasdesvios` el cual es una comparación entre la fecha que se inició la tarea y la fecha en la que se entregó.

La idea que tengo es que si `diasdesvios > 10` esa solicitud la pinte en rojo.

Alguien me puede dar alguna idea?

```js
If(Diasdesvios > 10){
   Fila de la solicitud se colorea en rojo
{
```

**NOTA**

No he intentado nada. Mas tengo la idea de usar una condicional

Answer (score 1):

En las propiedades de la fila, puedes poner una expresión y devolver un color, por ejemplo:

```
=IIF(Fields!Diasdesvios.Value > 10, "Red", "No Color")
```

La función IIF acepta 3 argumentos, una expresión booleana, el valor que devuelve si la primera expresión es verdadera y el valor si la expresión es falsa.

[image: Propiedades]

Hay más [ejemplos de expresiones](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms157328(v=sql.90)) que puedes usar en la documentación.